# Why is onedrive.exe running on the GPU?

Tags: laptop, gpu, windows-11, power-management, onedrive

I have laptop with an Nvidia GPU. When I disconnect power and the external screen it should switch over to the internal GPU instead of the Nvidia to reduce power consumption, but `onedrive.exe` is still running.

I can kill OneDrive with Armoury Crate and the NVIDIA GPU will switch off. Is there any reason that OneDrive uses the GPU in the first place and is there a way to prevent it from using it?

[image: onedrive.exe running on NVIDIA GPU]

- **OS**: Windows 11 home 10.0.22621 Build 22621.
- **Laptop**: ASUS TUF Gaming A15 FA507RR.
- **CPU**: AMD Ryzen 7 6800H with radeon graphics.
- **GPU**: Nvidia GeForce RTX 3070.

FWIW, to view the GPU activity, I checked "Display GPU Activity Icon in Notification Area." in the Nvidia control panel.

[image: Nvidia control panel, Display GPU Activity Icon in Notification Area.]

Comment: [Beware: Your Microsoft OneDrive could be under the spell of a crypto miner - Neowin](https://www.neowin.net/news/beware-your-microsoft-onedrive-could-be-under-the-spell-of-a-crypto-miner/)?

Comment: How exactly in specific detail did you view this information?  I would agree you are likely infected with malware.

Comment: @Ramhound, I added your requested information

Comment: I did some extra testing and onedrive only runs on the GPU when I start the laptop with the external screen connected. Also all applications that are moved to the external monitor run on the GPU.

Comment: Well, that explains it, external monitors more often than not only work with the dGPU. But in any case you should check with the usual tools to confirm is not the situation commented above.

Comment: OneDrive most certainly should NOT be using your GPU.  Looking at my own system you most certainly are infected with a cryptominer malware.

Comment: Malwarebytes and Windows Defender did not find anything